# Android app shuts down each time I click button

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication

I have an app u need to login or register  at first I use sqlite database I researched online nothing to find 
my problem is when I click on log in the app shuts down 
here is the function :

```
package com.example.i.projet;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class loginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
BaseDeDonee bdd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final EditText lemail =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.lemail);
    final EditText lpassword =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.lpassword);
    final Button sbotton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sbutton);
    final Button lbotton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.lbutton);

    if (lemail.getText().toString()=="" || lpassword.getText() .toString()==""){
        lemail.setError( "email is required!" );

        lemail.setHint("please enter email");
    }


    sbotton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(loginActivity.this,regestryActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    lbotton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (lemail.getText().toString()=="" || lpassword.getText() .toString()==""){
                lemail.setError( "email is required!" );

                lemail.setHint("please enter email");
            }else {
                boolean ress =bdd.finde(lemail.getText().toString(),lpassword.getText().toString());
                if (ress==true){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(loginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else  Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "wrong dont exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }




        }
    });





}
```

}

and data base class

```
package com.example.i.projet;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class BaseDeDonee extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Platforme.db";

public static final String TABLE_PERSONNE = "UsersTable";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "nom";
public static final String COL_3 = "prenom";
public static final String COL_4 = "numero_tel";
public static final String COL_5 = "profile";
public static final String COL_s = "password";
public static final String COL_k = "etat";


public static final String TABLE_COMPTE = "CompteTable";
public static final String COL_6 = "numero_compte";
public static final String COL_7 = "cle_compte";
public static final String COL_8 = "solde_courante";
public static final String COL_9 = "type_compte";

public static final String TABLE_OPPERATIONS = "OpperationsTable";
public static final String COL_10 = "num_opp";
public static final String COL_11 = "type_opp";
public static final String COL_12 = "date_opp";
public static final String COL_13 = "montant_opp";
public static final String COL_14 = "solde_courante";
//+etat de l'opp pour avoir est que personel ou du busness

public static final String TABLE_PRODUITS = "ProductsTable";

public static final String COL_15 = "nom_prod";
public static final String COL_16 = "type_prod";
public static final String COL_17 = "PrixUnit_prod";
public static final String COL_18 = "quantite_prod";
public static final String COL_19 = "PrixTotal_prod";

public static final String TABLE_FACTURES = "FacturesTable";

public static final String COL_20 = "num_fact";
public static final String COL_21 = "type_fact";
public static final String COL_22 = "Montant_fact";
public static final String COL_23 = "date_fact";

public static final String TABLE_IDENTIFICATION = "IdentificationTable";

public static final String COL_24 = "profile";
public static final String COL_25 = "password";

public static final String TABLE_DECAISSEMENT = "DecaissementTable";

public static final String COL_26 = "num_opp";
public static final String COL_27 = "type_compte";
public static final String COL_28 = "piecejustificatif";

public static final String TABLE_Temp = "tempTable";



public BaseDeDonee(Context context ) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);



}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_PERSONNE +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,nom TEXT,prenom TEXT,numero_tel INTEGER,profile TEXT,password Text,etat Text)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_COMPTE +" (numero_compte INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,cle_compte INTEGER,solde_courante DOUBLE,type_compte TEXT,ID INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_PERSONNE)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_PRODUITS +" (nom_prod TEXT PRIMARY KEY,type_prod TEXT,PrixUnit_prod DOUBLE,quantite_prod INTEGER,PrixTotal_prod DOUBLE,num_opp INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_OPPERATIONS)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_FACTURES +" (num_fact INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,type_fact TEXT,Montant_fact DOUBLE,date_fact DATE,num_opp INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_OPPERATIONS,ID INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_PERSONNE)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_OPPERATIONS +" (num_opp INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,type_opp TEXT,montant_opp DOUBLE,date_opp DATE,ID INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_PERSONNE ,solde_courante DOUBLE REFERENCES TABLE_COMPTE)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_IDENTIFICATION +" (profile TEXT REFERENCES TABLE_PERSONNE PRIMARY KEY ,password TEXT REFERENCES TABLE_PERSONNE)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_DECAISSEMENT + " (piecejustificatif TEXT PRIMARY KEY,num_opp INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_OPPERATIONS,type_compte TEXT REFERENCES TABLE_COMPTE)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_Temp + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES TABLE_PERSONNE )");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_PERSONNE+TABLE_COMPTE+TABLE_PRODUITS+TABLE_FACTURES+TABLE_OPPERATIONS+TABLE_IDENTIFICATION+TABLE_DECAISSEMENT+TABLE_Temp);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String nom ,String prenom ,String tel,String profile,String password ,String etat){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_PERSONNE,new String[]{"*"},"profile =?",new String[]{profile},null,null,null);

    contentValues.put(COL_2,nom);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,prenom);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,tel);
    contentValues.put(COL_5,profile);
    contentValues.put(COL_s,password);
    contentValues.put(COL_k,etat);
    if(res!=null && res.moveToFirst()){
        return false;
    }else{
    long result=  db.insert(TABLE_PERSONNE, null, contentValues);

    if (result==-1){
        return false;
    }else return true; }





}
public boolean insertl(String profile ,String password ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues ContentVlues = new ContentValues();
    ContentVlues.put(COL_24,profile);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_25,password);



    long  result =db.insert(TABLE_IDENTIFICATION,null,ContentVlues);
    if (result==-1)
        return false;
    else return true ;

}


public boolean insertfacture(String type ,String Montantfact, String date){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues ContentVlues = new ContentValues();
    ContentVlues.put(COL_21,type);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_22,Montantfact);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_23,date);
    long  result =db.insert(TABLE_FACTURES,null,ContentVlues);
    if (result==-1)
        return false;
    else return true ;

}


public boolean insertCompte(String numero_compte ,String cle_compte, String solde_courante,String type_compte ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues ContentVlues = new ContentValues();
    ContentVlues.put(COL_6,numero_compte);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_7,cle_compte);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_8,solde_courante);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_9,type_compte);
    long  result =db.insert(TABLE_COMPTE,null,ContentVlues);
    if (result==-1)
        return false;
    else return true ;

}
public boolean insertProduit(String nom_prod ,String type_prod, String PrixUnit_prod,String  quantite_prod,String PrixTotal_prod){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues ContentVlues = new ContentValues();

    ContentVlues.put(COL_15,nom_prod);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_16,type_prod);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_17,PrixUnit_prod);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_18,quantite_prod);
    ContentVlues.put(COL_19,PrixTotal_prod);


    long  result =db.insert(TABLE_PRODUITS,null,ContentVlues);

    if (result==-1)
        return false;
    else return true ;

}


public boolean inseloginid(int  id  ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues ContentVlues = new ContentValues();
    ContentVlues.put(COL_1,id);
    long  result =db.insert(TABLE_Temp,null,ContentVlues);
    if (result==-1)
        return false;
    else return true ;

}


public Cursor afficherinfoP (){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_PERSONNE,null );

    return res;
}


public Boolean finde(String lemail, String lpass) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_IDENTIFICATION, null, "profile=? AND password=?",new String[]{lemail,lpass},null,null,null);


    if(res!=null && res.moveToFirst()){
        res.close();

        return false;
    }else {
        res.close();
        return true;
    }

}
public int findID (String lemail){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select 'id'  from "+TABLE_PERSONNE+"where 'profile'="+lemail,null );

    int k = res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("id"));
    return k;
}
public int tempID (){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_Temp,null);
    int k = res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("id"));
    return k ;

}
public double rapportJ(String date,int id ){
    Double k= Double.valueOf(0);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("Select * from"+TABLE_FACTURES+"where date_fact="+date+"and id="+id,null);
    while (res.moveToNext()){
        k=k+ res.getDouble(2);
    }
    Cursor ress=db.rawQuery("Select * from"+TABLE_OPPERATIONS+"where date_opp="+date+"and id="+id,null);
    while (ress.moveToNext()){
        k=k+ ress.getDouble(2);
    }
    return k;
}
```

}

stack trace [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHFfu.png)

Comment: Can you post your stackrace

Comment: i added it and login java 39 is the line booleen ress =.....

Comment: are `lemail` and `lpassword` != `null`?

Comment: Stacktrace from `logcat` is what am asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the stack trace, it seems like either lemail or lpassword are null. Make sure you use the correct IDs in the findViewById method.

```
EditText lemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lemail);
EditText lpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lpassword);
```

That method will return null if the view wasn't found.

EDIT: It seems like you're not instantiating the bdd variable.

Comment: i did use the correct ID

Comment: What's the type of variable bdd? And where does it come from?

Comment: bdd is an instanse of my database class BaseDeDonee

Comment: Where are you instantiating it?

Comment: in login activity class

Comment: Please, add the code to the original question. I'll edit my answer after seeing it.

Comment: i added the new code

Comment: you did not instatiate bdd

Comment: thank you so much and i needed to change the query to

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean validateLogin(String lemail, String lpass, Context context) {

    DatabaseHandler database = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();`

    //WHERE clause
    String selection = "profile=? AND lpass=?";

    //WHERE clause arguments
    String[] selectionArgs = {lemail, userPass};
    Cursor c = null;

    try{

    c = db.query(TABLE_IDENTIFICATION,, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    c.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int i = c.getCount();
    if(i <= 0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Login..\nTry Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}//validate Login
```

Comment: thank yo so much ts been a while trayin to fix queries with the try and catch thing ecrything will work right thank you my brother